# Adding role attribute to native tagLib in groovy

Tags: grails, taglib

Anyone know how to add a accessibility role attribute to a li tag inside grails validationTagLib.groovy renderErrors method.

I have a custom tag that calls the validationTagLib.groovy renderErrors tag.

```
Closure myError = { attrs ->
   out << renderErrors(bean:request.getAttribute("beanName"), field:request.getAttribute("field")) 
}
```

The issue here is renderErrors displays a li tag with the message error and i'm trying to add a role="alert" and a class="alert-message" onto that tag, but because its a native Taglib I can't change the stricture. So trying to see if there is anyway to pass in an attribute that would get added to the li tag. So far I can't see that happening based on what the code structure is. http://docs.huihoo.com/grails/1.3.7/ref/Tags/renderErrors.html#

So any ideas how to do this ? I've just started writing custom tagLibs so go easy on me :)

Comment: You've linked to documentation for Grails 1.3.7. Is that what version you are using?

Comment: Oops no i'm using Grails 2.4.4